# Performance of algorithms that loop more/less but with same number of O(1) operations

Tags: loops, optimization, time-complexity

Whenever I see algorithm optimization, I see lots of talk about reducing loop count. Often times, I see multiple operations being incorporated into one loop that were originally done separately.

Ultimately, the same number of O(1) processes are performed. It's just that one algorithm splits them into multiple iterations. Is there honestly a performance benefit to combining operations, from a scaling perspective?

Overly simplified example. I'm aware this is not a good example because the inner time complexity operations are low compared to the act of even incrementing `i`, but you get my point.

```
let tally1 = 0
let tally2 = 0

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tally1 += 1
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tally2 += 1
}

// vs

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tally1 += 1
  tally2 += 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the second version will perform better because all the operations that make up the loop only have to be executed once.

So while the operations executed inside the loop will perform no better or worse, the overall execution time will be shorter.

Whether that is relevant or not largely depends on how expensive the operations inside the loop are. If they are cheap, the overhead of the loop will be noticeable, and it may be worth optimizing the code. If they are expensive, it might not be worth the effort.

Besides performance, clarity of the code is also a good thing. So if it doesn't matter form a performance point of view, you should choose the code that is better to read.

Comment: Yes, what you describe is the source of my confusion. My thoughts were that very complex algorithms inside an enumerable don't benefit in a meaningful way that would justify spaghetti code. Is what I described just now an accurate assessment of your answer?

Comment: I would say yes.

Answer (score 1):

In very short loops, the overhead of the loop construction itself (increment and termination test) is "significant". To the point that compilers may perform "loop unrolling" optimizations, i.e. replicate the loop body to avoid performing the intermediate tests (with some extra care to handle termination).

Loop merging can bring similar speedups.

When the loop bodies are more complicated, the loop overhead becomes more negligible, and performance can even degrade when you merge the loops because you may saturate the number of required registers or degrade cache efficiency.

For ordinary programs, these kinds of micro-optimization are often not worth the effort. They are more relevant in the development of reusable code of general usefulness, such as the BLAS routines.